# Should each website be its own `node.js` process

Tags: node.js, load-balancing

We host about 150 websites (possibly scaling to 300+) that we are considering migrating to `node.js`. Most of the sites are fairly low traffic <1mil pageviews per month.

Should each website be it's own node.js process, or should we serve all websites using the same node.js process (or small set of load balanced processes). Is there a technical limit or a reasonable limit to the number of node processes per server?

**Process per site:** Feels inefficient, but I don't know if it actually is inefficient. Would ensure one buggy site doesn't affect other sites.

**Process per core/small set of processes:** Likely higher performance, but what happens when I need to update a sites codebase, won't it take down other sites? Also, code failures in one site would affect other sites.

Ideally, I would prefer one process per site so that we could host all sites from each worker server. That way when load increases we can just spin up another identical worker server and load balance between the two without having to arbitrarily say SiteA goes to ServerA and SiteB goes to ServerB. Any `node.js` gurus available to offer some wisdom?

All static file requests will be handled likely by Nginx or something like Varnish.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of issues at play here.  The big picture answer is, it depends...  as it always does when you bring in the whole "performance" discussion.  That being said, the simplest way to get a solid Node set up is to note the following basic facts about NodeJS, and I will also comment on their implications as they pertain to your questions.

- The concurrency you get with Node works really good in certain situations, namely IO heavy operations.  What we're really talking about here is minimizing the amount of downtime to wait for the next request.  Because of this, Node works really well in an environment where there is one process per core on a machine.  Node does really well at maximizing the amount of CPU available to serve requests under heavy load.  This being said, if you have literally ZERO other work going on in your even loop, you can see minor performance increases (in terms of max requests/second/processor core) by having multiple node processes per core.  But, I've never seen any benefit from increasing this number past 3.  Even under circumstances where the entire event loop was literally just a file server.
- On the process per site comment.  This is a bad idea for many reasons.  For one, a well put together node server can process thousands of requests per second.  Our (company name omitted) servers, hosted through Amazon EC2 on medium clusters (lots of ram, mid CPU clock, 4 cores), typically fail around 3000 requests per second per cluster.  Our servers do a fair bit of CPU work, for simple file servers I'm sure you can do much better.  Strictly speaking, sure, per site, you will be able to serve more requests by launching each site in its own process/core/escalating quickly here!  But it's not necessary from a cost and over complication of your architecture point of view.  What I WOULD recommend, is investing in a setup with a lot of RAM.  The ability for your server to cache often requested files will effect your performance infinitely more than launching an abundance of processes for a given machine.
- On the whole RAM thing.  The number of processes you want to launch for a given core is dependant on two things.  One is how much synchronous work done in your event loop.  The more synchronous work, the more time between a given request coming in and the event loop being ready to adress the next one.  If you have a busy event loop, you will be in a situation where you require more processes/CPU Core.  The other thing that can effect this, particularly relevant for file servers, is the amount of RAM.  Node runs much better in a high ram environment, but you can say this about ANY file server really...  What this has to do with, is the number of active asynchronous operations.  One downside of the way node works, is under heavy loads, you can get a large number of event handlers active at once.  This is great for concurrency/simplicity, however, if your server is busy waiting around for a lot of async disk/IO to happen it will slow down and crash much sooner than if you had plenty of RAM.  If you don't have enough RAM to handle all of these event handlers, you will want to keep to the 1 process/core arrangement.  Otherwise, it is easier for Node to spin up many event handlers simultaneously, and again cause you to crash sooner than you would otherwise.

I don't really have enough information to tell you what you SHOULD do.  This depends entirely too much on the architecture of your specific server, sites, size of your sites, amount of data... etc.  But these three pieces of knowledge are the basic things that help you get the most out of your Node server.  To be honest, your idea about load balancing mixed with the considerations above, should do nicely for you.  Surely, microoptimizations are possible, but if you do these things, you should easily see requests/second in the thousands before you start experiencing crashes because of DDOS type of conditions.

Comment: Appreciate the thorough comment. If it helps clarify these apps don't need to be cutting edge high performance. The reason for one process per site isn't for performance, it's to deal with issues such as fault tolerance and updating code without affecting other sites. I'd much rather run a few processes per core as you suggest, but how do I handle my two issues when I do that? Also, the plan is to have all static file requests go through Nginx, Varnish or something like that. Node shouldn't be serving those.

Comment: First off, good error handling and the such is a given.  But also, as a fallback you can look into modules like this: https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever or this if you like the idea of a process for a given site: https://github.com/haraldrudell/nodegod

Comment: "The reason for one process per site isn't for performance, it's to deal with issues such as fault tolerance and updating code without affecting other sites." @ChrisCM, I'm really interested in that.

Answer (score 1):

No, don't do it. Keep it simple! And check out http://12factor.net/.

A few hundred processes is nothing compared to the simplicity you otherwise lose. It would be a terrible decision, on so many levels, to have more than one site (or, "logical application unit") served by a single Node process.

If you're asking this question, you may want to explore Node more before you "migrate" to Node. Error handling and separation of concerns are more complicated in Node than in other situations. Specifically, neither the `domain` nor `cluster` APIs are mature. But really it's the philosophy of clean and simple application deployment that you'd be violating. I could go on and on.

Comment: My ideal scenario is to have one process per site. What I'm asking is are there problems with doing that. Will I be introducing massive bloat overhead by having 200+ processes on a single box. In example, in our current JVM environment the idea of 200+ JVM instances is laughable. The box would die before it got over 20. What I need to know is if this same limitation exists in node.

Comment: I'm not avoiding answering your question so much as I'm saying that you have no choice. That's /the/ way to do it, not because I'm closed minded about thinking of more resource-efficient solutions, but because you'd really be creating a complicated mess for yourself if you didn't do it this way. Sometimes you simply can't just run everything on one box. Node processes can clock in at 10-30MB

Comment: And of course it definitely depends on your hardware. A box can have 500MB of RAM or 5000MB of RAM. I think a big box could handle 200 nodes. But, hey, why not get 4 medium boxes?

Comment: Looks like the lightest-weight lightweight HTTP server in Node (like one you see in HTTP server examples) is 4-8 MB in RAM depending on arch.